# XML Transform locate a node based on values in neighboring node

Tags: xpath, xdt-transform

I'm trying to set attributes for a node that has no key or name, but it neighboring node can be identified by its `name` attribute. But I' really struggling to come up with a locator expression to choose the correct node.

The source xml is:

```
</configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            ...
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            ...
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and I tried

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            ...
            <dependentAssembly>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
                    xdt:Locator="XPath(//../assemblyIdentity[@name='System.Web.WebPages'])"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            ...
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But it won't update the `oldVersion` attribute of the `bindingRedirect` node and if I omit the `xdt:Locator="..."` entirely it changes the value for all `bindingRedirect` nodes.

**Update:**
Using [this](http://xpather.com/) online xpath evaluator and the answer of Jack Fleeting I found an xpath expression which correctly selects the node I want

```
//dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[@name='System.Web.WebPages']/following-sibling::bindingRedirect
```

the problem now seams to be that the transform engine does not know how to handle this.
I tried to use the transformations `Replace` and `SetAttributes`, none of which resulted in an update of the node.
Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to modify the value of `<bindingRedirec>`, your xpath expression doesn't select it.

try chainging

```
xdt:Locator="XPath(//../assemblyIdentity[@name='System.Web.WebPages'])"/>
```

to

```
xdt:Locator="XPath(//../assemblyIdentity[@name='System.Web.WebPages']/following-sibling::bindingRedirect)"/>
```

and see if it works.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow at work and will report how it went.